# Getting error log in console to add UISearchViewController in tabbar item tvOS 10.0

Tags: ios, ios10, tvos, apple-tv, tvos10

I'veve updated my Apple tv 9.2.2 to 10.0 and update code. I've used `UISearchViewController` in tabbar item. Every things is working fine but now I'm getting error log in console only tvOS 10.0 not in tvOS 9.2.2

> [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
>   2016-10-06 11:49:26.899645 wral[152:3384] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.

I did R&D for this issue and find out need to add key in info.plist but I'm not understating which key is require to add in info.plist.

Please suggest it which key is require to add for using `UISearchViewController` in info.plist.

Comment: I am facing same issue in tvOS 10.0.

Answer (score 0):

There are many keys are there in `ios 10` , so you have to search that which one is appropriate for you. for example, if you are using `camara` or `photolibrary` then you need to add `Privacy - Camera Usage Description` or `Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description`. So take a look at [Apple document about Information Property List Key Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html) and decide that which key you required!

May be you require `Privacy - TV Provider Usage Description` !

Comment: I have used this key but same log is print in console.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue when using entering text on a sorts of textfield on iOS 10, Xcode 8. There are no keys to be entered in the `info.plist` that will fix this.

> [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
>
> [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.